# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();
```

For some reason,  I cannot get this three lines of code above to work. Here is what i have done :

1. I added the ZF2 library into my include_path (at runtime) using set_include_path
2. I verified that it is working fine.
   calling require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php'; does not return any error messages
3. But when i call :
   $loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
   $loader->register();
   I get the "Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' not found" error. I am quite confused why the above is not working. Am i missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this code in a custom namespace? Try prefixing the class with a backslash to indicate the root namespace -- `new \Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader()`

Comment: Hrmmm maybe not -- looks like PHP includes the namespace prefix in the error message in that case. (At least in 5.5)

Comment: This code is not in a custom name space. Also that is all i have in a file besides the code that adds Zend library to the "init_path". There must be something missing. Also if i remove the Zend\Loader and call the class StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true)); directly, it is still not working.

Comment: I found out what the issue was. I had another instance of Zend library (1.X) in my php.ini  that was interferring with the new Zend 2.0 that i installed. It would seems that the can't both coexist if you have them globally defined in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another instance of Zend library (1.X) in my php.ini that was interfering with the new Zend 2.0 that i had installed. It would seem that they can't both coexist, if you have one of them globally defined in php.ini. It is best to add them at runtime if you want to run both version simultaneously.